# BigQuery get average daily trend metrics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker

I want to know the average amount of daily distinct users for our Platform.
The limit is that I have to implement this into our BI Tool (Looker) which creates SQL for BigQuery, so I can only put some custom sql code into the select statement, and cannot arbitrarily create the query.

I found a solution which works on a small amount of data but when I extend it, the hard limit of 100MB for an Array throws an error.

The concatenation and splitting is to decrease the array size. I used a STRUCT(id, date) first but you cannot use the DISTINCT with a STRUCT.

The problem with the filesize does not appear within the function, I cannot even use only the ARRAY_AGG(

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION trend_daily_avg(columns_arr ARRAY<STRING>) AS ((
    SELECT AVG(value)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT columns_arr.value_column) as value,
        FROM (
            SELECT
                SPLIT(concatstring, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as value_column,
                SPLIT(concatstring, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as time_column,
            FROM UNNEST(columns_arr) concatstring
        ) columns_arr
        GROUP BY columns_arr.time_column
    )
));
WITH dummy_data as (
    SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0003 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "12-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL 
    SELECT "12-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname
)
SELECT
    hostname,
    count(distinct full_visitor_id) as users_dedup,
    trend_daily_avg(ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT
        CONCAT(view_date, " ", full_visitor_id) IGNORE NULLS
    )) as average_trend, # This works for a small amount of data but not in production
    ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT
        CONCAT(view_date, " ", full_visitor_id) IGNORE NULLS
    ) as average_trend, # This also doesnt work, the upper query fails at this part
FROM ( # Subselect cannot be touched as it cannot be integrated into the BI tool
    SELECT
        view_date,
        full_visitor_id,
        hostname, # More dimensions get dynamically added and then grouped
    FROM dummy_data
)
GROUP BY hostname;
```

Can I somehow either increase the max row size in BigQuery, or rewrite the query so that it doesn't have to create the massive Array?

Edit:
One solution which works is to add each day (for day granularity) or month (for monthly granularity) separately into an array. It's definitely not an ideal solution and very inefficient, but works. Is there a way to make this more efficient? As just the day and id on a month have around 30GB of Data, and having ~1000 Subqueries on a three year range is pretty bad.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION avg_array(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
    SELECT 
        AVG(val) 
    FROM(
        SELECT val 
        FROM UNNEST(arr) val 
        where val > 0
    )
)
);
 
select
count(distinct id) as users_dedup,
avg_array([
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-01-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-02-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-03-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-04-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-05-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-06-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-07-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-08-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-09-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-10-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-11-01' then id else null end),
    count(distinct case when day = '2021-12-01' then id else null end)
]) as avg_monthly_users 

from (
select '123' as id, '2021-01-01' as day
union all
select '456' as id, '2021-02-01' as day
union all
select '123' as id, '2021-03-01' as day
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of large arrays the maximum limit on the size of a single row is reached.  I tried to get the average number of daily distinct users without using arrays and it's working fine.

```
WITH dummy_data as (
   SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "10-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0003 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "11-10-2021" as view_date, 0001 as full_visitor_id, "group-1" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "12-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname UNION ALL
   SELECT "12-10-2021" as view_date, 0002 as full_visitor_id, "group-2" as hostname
)
SELECT hostname, AVG(c) as avg_users FROM  (SELECT hostname , view_date, COUNT(DISTINCT full_visitor_id) as c
       FROM (# Subselect cannot be touched as it cannot be integrated into the BI tool
   SELECT
       view_date,
       full_visitor_id,
       hostname, # More dimensions get dynamically added and then grouped
   FROM dummy_data
)GROUP BY hostname, view_date) GROUP BY hostname
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: While yes, this does give the correct numbers I cannot build this into the BI tool. I want a measure which does the calculation, which can only be inserted in the Select part of the query. Everything after the From I cannot really modify since it's dynamically created by Looker, depending on the chosen dimensions.

Comment: You could create a [derived table](https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/learning-lookml/derived-tables) in Looker to change the `from` part of the query.